# js for in recursive function not working

Tags: javascript, recursion

My Code is in JS not working but in c is working. Why?
Why For in calling recursive function not working?
What can i do for in recursive function? I must make this project with JavaScript.

JS CODE

```
<a onClick="req(1)">Click</a>
<script>
function req(s){
    if(s<5){
        console.log(s);
        for(i=0;i<s;i++){
            req(s+1);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

This code return this value :
1
2
3
4

C CODE

```
#include <stdio.h>

void req(int s){
    if(s<5){
        printf("%d\n",s);
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0;i<s;i++){
            req(s+1);
        }
    }
}

void main(){
 req(1);

}
```

It is :

1
2
3
4
4
4
3
4
4
4

Comment: what is the logic behind this?

Comment: I need this. Up code is for examle. I make my home work. I make Outomata Theory in Push Down Machine. I must make with JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always. Declare. Your. Variables.

Otherwise they become global in sloppy mode.

```js
function req(s) {
  if(s<10) {
    console.log(s);
    for(var i=0; i<s; i++) {
      req(s+1);
    }
  }
}
req(1);
```

Comment: You are super! :)